# How to convert generic variants instance without the redundancy match cases?

Tags: ocaml

I have the following generic variant type:

```ml
type 'a t = A | B | C | D | E | Value of 'a
```

and some function that converts `int t` to `string t`

```ml
let int_to_sting = function
  | Value x -> Value (string_of_int x)
  | some    -> some
```

This function is uncompilable because of

> | some    -> **some**
>   Error: This expression has type int t but an expression was expected
>   of type   string t
>   Type int is not compatible

Even it has type annotation.

```ml
let int_to_sting : int t -> string t = function
  | Value x -> Value (string_of_int x)
  | some    -> some
```

I can rewrite it with

```ml
let int_to_sting = function
  | Value x -> Value (string_of_int x)
  | A       -> A
  | B       -> B
  | C       -> C
  | D       -> D
  | E       -> E
```

But the long list of constructors looks redundancy.
Is it possible to convert `some` in my first implementation to avoid this noisy code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it slightly less redundant by both enumerating *and* binding them to a name:

```
let int_to_sting = function
  | Value x -> Value (string_of_int x)
  | (A | B | C | D | E) as some -> some
```

Another option that is OBVIOUSLY NOT SAFE and that you DEFINITELY SHOULDN'T USE is to circumvent the type system using `Obj.magic`:

```
let int_to_sting = function
  | Value x -> Value (string_of_int x)
  | some    -> (Obj.magic (some: int t): string t)
```

This happens to work because the representation of these values are the same regardless of the type argument. But if you were to add another constructor that is not... then you crash and burn.